# Configuring Webpack to create bundles for groups of pages in Next JS

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, next.js, webpack-splitchunks

We are building a fairly large app, with quite a few pages. These pages can be divided to several distinct groups of pages that share many common dependencies among them, that are not used by pages in the other groups.

If I were to sketch a rough simplified dependency tree, it would be something along these lines:

[image]

So basically, two "classes" of pages, `PA` and `PB`, with dependencies I'd like to split into bundles in the following way:
Dependencies shared among all pages (`D-3` in this case), which I'd like to have in the `commons` bundle;

- Dependencies that are only are shared between the `PA` pages (`D-1` and `D-2`), which I'd like to have in a `PA` bundle;
- Dependencies that are only are shared between the `PB` pages (`D-4` and `D-5`), which I'd like to have in a `PB` bundle;
- Dependencies that are only used by a single page (`D-6`), which should be part of that page's bundle

With the current setup, because `D-3`, `D-4` and `D-5` are used by more than half the pages in the app, they are bundled into the `commons` bundle, and therefore also loaded by `PA` type pages.

Is there a way to extend next.Js's webpack config through `next.config.js` to produce the bundles this way using `optimization.splitChunks`?